# Git commit a config file to be overridden by user

Tags: git, config, gitignore

There is a Git project which needs some local configurations to build. Is it possible that I commit a file say **env.config** and anybody who clones the repo locally overrides this config file according to his needs. I want Git to untrack any further change in **env.config** while commit.

I could add entry to *.gitignore* but this will also remove the default version of file from repo.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

The usual thing I do in such cases is to add **env.config.template** to the repository and the actual **env.config** to .gitignore. Each user is supposed to create their own **env.config** basing on the template.

The other solution is to ask users not to commit their changes or even prevent accidental commits including the config file in a git-hook. However, I think adding a template is a bit cleaner: it requires a special operation (copying) only once and does not require care with every commit.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Adding template looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

In my oppinion i would rather add the file as an `env.config.example` or something like that and add an entry to the `.gitignore` for `env.config`.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 main options to do it:

1. `.gitignore` - Git will ignore the file from now on on all the clones you made.
2. `assume unchanged` - Will temporary ignore the file locally on the local clone until turned off.
3. `smudge/clean` filters

---

### ***`.gitignore`***

The problem with this way is that once you have commute the file to the repository it will not be ignored.

You first have to add it to the `.gitignore` and then `force` add it to the the repository and commit.

---

### ***`--[no-]assume-unchanged`***

If you still want the file in the repository (as asked) you should use the `assume-unchanged` flag on the tracked file.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

---

### ***`Smudge/clean`***

Read all about it and to set it up here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

> It turns out that you can write your own filters for doing substitutions in files on **commit/checkout**.
>
> These are called `clean` and `smudge` filters.
>
> In the `.gitattributes` file, you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out (“smudge”, see Figure 8-2) and just before they’re staged (“clean”, see Figure 8-3).
>
> These filters can be set to do all sorts of fun things.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git update-index` for your case.

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged env.config
```

When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, git stops checking the working tree files for possible modifications.